# XML Web Service in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, liferay

I am a newbie to Liferay. I am using Liferay 6.1. My requirements is to develop web service that will return only XML feed. I can see that Liferay has already made it easy when it comes to JSON, SOAP or WSDL. What I want to do is to select data from my database and return XML when the portlet is called just like the way it is done in the case of Servlets.

I will be very grateful if you describe in short or if you refer to some blogs where the solution has been elaborated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access Liferay's JSON webservice api you can use

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws
```

for you local server (change host for other servers)
In order to understand how it works, there is a very detailed explanation on liferay's community : `http://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/yet-another-liferay-json-service-example 
update on :`http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13489024`
and here is the official documentation :

```
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/json-web-services
```

Comment: thanks for the Update. But i need a way to generate only XMl.

Comment: there are a number of libraries to convert json to XML. If you doing it in a specific format I am afraid you have to code it, checkout our liferay's json servlet and either make a change to it through EXT or you can implement your own. JSONServlet (example http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/279-how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-java/)

Comment: Looks like I don't have another way out except this. Thanks buddy.